# Saving timestamp in mysql database in UNIX format

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have this events table in my database, in this table the column event_time carries current time stamp, by default the format of time stamp is like "1970-01-01 00:00:01", is there any way that this default format can be changed to UNIX time stamp format?

```
EVENTS table:-
  `global_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_creator` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_type` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `event_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

,

Comment: UNIX_TIMESTAMP will convert any time to UNIX FORMAT but will not change the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want **[`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)**

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1989-01-01 00:00:01')
```

will have a result of `599616001`

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/4203)

Comment: what I am asking is that, If I can change the time format of TIMESTAMP stored in MySQL, I just wanted to avoid converting it to UNIX_TIMESTAMP in every single query